# Android Java Chain layout changes into one line instead of four

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I got the following code

```
txtEditItemName.setClickable(true);
txtEditItemName.setCursorVisible(true);
txtEditItemName.setFocusable(true);
txtEditItemName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Is there a way to chain them together? Something like this:

```
txtEditItemName.setClickable(true).setCursorVisible(true).setFocusable(true).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: In kotlin you can write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those commands are voided so they don't return the object which would make it impossible to chain the commands together.

Answer (score 0):

Try kotlin with scope function

txtEditItemName.apply {
isClickable = true

```
        isCursorVisible = true
        isFocusable = true
        isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    }
```